# PCI Compliance with ASP.Net Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

So if you have an ecommerce app and you used the awesome ASP.Net Membership Provider you have a working user authentication system out-of-the-box.

Now.. your customers says "Please make my site PCI Compliant"

So it seems like there are handful of *tweaks* that you'll need to make,
such as:

- enforce symbols in new passwords
- minimum password length of 7

These are easy ones, you can set them all in the web.config in the Membership Provider section.

However, a PCI requirement like:

1. Disable inactive accounts after 90 days

It seems like you need some kind of c# script + scheduled task to handle this.
**Has anyone every made nice nice utility script/class that takes care of all of these extra PCI issues?**
It seems like a very generic script and would work on most sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `SqlMembershipProvider` for membership, you can try out this SQL script to lock out accounts that have not logged in in 90 days.

```
update mydatabase.dbo.aspnet_Membership
set IsLockedOut = 1, LastLockoutDate = GETDATE()
where LastLoginDate < GETDATE() - 90
```